# Python: Seeing all files in Hex

Tags: python, hex

I am writing a python script which looks at common computer files and examines them for similar bytes, words, double word's.  Though I need/want to see the files in Hex, ande cannot really seem to get python to open a simple file in python.  I have tried codecs.open with hex as the encoding, but when I operate on the file descriptor it always spits back

```
      File "main.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 38, in main
    process_file(sys.argv[1])
  File "main.py", line 27, in process_file
    seeker(line.rstrip("\n"))
  File "main.py", line 15, in seeker
    for unit in f.read(2):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 666, in read
    return self.reader.read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/codecs.py", line 472, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 50, in decode
    return hex_decode(input,errors)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/hex_codec.py", line 42, in hex_decode
    output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found





def seeker(_file):
 f = codecs.open(_file, "rb", "hex")
 for LINE in f.read():
      print LINE
 f.close()
```

I really just want to see files, and operate on them as if it was in a hex editor like xxd.  Also is it possible to read a file in increments of maybe a word at a time.

No this is not homework.

Comment: Is there a reason why they absolutely have to be in "hex"? After all, the hex format you see in hex editors is really just a visual representation of data that is actually binary... bytes/words/dwords are binary values, hex is just an easier way to humans to visualize them.

Comment: Well binary would also be fine, but hex is smaller and universal enough for good use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`codecs.open(_file, "rb", "hex")` is trying to **decode** the file's contents as being hex, which is why it's failing on you.

Considering your other "word at a time" target (I assume you mean "computer word", i.e. 32 bits?), you'll be better off encapsulating the open file into a class of your own.  E.g.:

```
class HexFile(object):
    def __init__(self, fp, wordsize=4):
        self.fp = fp
        self.ws = wordsize
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            data = self.fp.read(self.ws)
            if not data: break
            yield data.encode('hex')
```

plus whatever other utility methods you'd find helpful, of course.

Comment: Thank you Alex, though I must say I have never seen this method before of file representation.  I take it HexFile takes a descriptor? maybe you can explain a bit more if you have time, I am quite interested.

Comment: Alex is just creating a wrapper class that wraps around a file descriptor object and allows you to iterate over it in word-sized blocks.

Comment: @Recursion, you just code `f=HexFile(open('data','rb'))` and then `for hexword in f: ...`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "file representation" -- as Amber says this is just a utility wrapper.

Comment: Thank you Alex, can you suggest a place where I can learn more about this.

Comment: @Recursion, learn more about what?  If Python programming in general, that's what I've tried to do in my two books, Python Cookbook and Python in a Nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a set number of bytes by passing an integer argument to `read`:

```
32bits = file.read(4)
```

You can seek to a position in the file using `seek`:

```
file.seek(100) # Seeks to byte 100
```

Answer (score 1):

if this will be more clear... :
def hexfile(file_path):
    fp=open(file_path)
    while True:
        data = fp.read(4)
        if not data: break
        print data.encode('hex')

file_path is something like "C:/somedir/filename.ext"
it nice method btw it will work nicely for me. :)