# how to compare hex files in python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, file, hex

I have big data hex files from which I need to compare some hex values.When i read through python read it automatically converts it into ascii and so I have to decode it again.How can i directly read file in hex??

Till now i have tried using Intelhex python package but it is throwing an error :
 intelhex.HexRecordError: Hex files contain invalid record.So is there any issues with my files only?

How much performance difference it is going to make if I successfully read hex data without decoding

Comment: What do you mean by "hex file"? A file containing a sequence of `0-9a-f` characters? Or a binary file you created/modified with a hex editor?

Comment: See alex's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2894216/674039)

Comment: Stefano---exactly a file containing a sequence of 0-9a-f

Comment: win---It seems u used the encoding method.Even i have done the same but i need an alternate method to increase performance.

Comment: So if you have a file containing the characters "4", "8", "6", "9", then Python automatically translates it to "Hi" when you read it? Very strange. Can you post some code that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: show `print(repr(open('input_file', 'rb').read(10)))`

Comment: Kevin---very true.That's y i m asking how to read in hex as i want to compare this data with only hex values

Comment: Sebastian----My hex file if of 69 bytes tupple.so these are 69 bytes with print(repr(open('input_file', 'rb').read(69)))----\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xe6\x00\xa1I\x8d

Comment: @Aman Jagga: don' put relevant info in comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: it seems using IntelHex library is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

split file into hex words consisting of purely `[0-9a-fA-F]` characters then `int(word, 16)` will change a word to a normal python integer. You can directly compare integers.

Alternatively you can keep the hex words and then convert an integer to a hex string using `'{0:x}'.format(someinteger)`, prior to comparing the hex strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = open('input_file', 'rb').read(10)
>>> s
'\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xe6\x00\xa1I\x8d'
```

It is an ordinary sequence of bytes. If a byte is in ascii range then it is shown as the corresponding character in the representation e.g.,`s[-2] == 'I'`. The byte is the same (`73` in decimal form), it is just shown in a human readable form.

You don't need to do any conversion to compare bytestrings (`a[2:10] == b[4:12]` works). Python does not decode your files to hex, ascii, or anything else unless you ask. Just make sure you open the files in binary mode (`rb`).